# Uppercase folder store yii always return index

Tags: url, yii, uppercase

I have create a Yii app. I store it in /testyii

I had create and rewrite URL. Everthing is OK.

But now, when i try to access by localhost/Testyii/about (uppercase letter T)

It always return me to index. It's ok when i access by localhost/testyii/about

Comment: please show what you have in rewrite url?

Answer (score 0):

In componet urlManager add this

```
'caseSensitive'=>false
```

Comment: Here it's'

<pre>urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
     'caseSensitive'=>false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller><action>/<param>/' => '<controller>/<action>/',
                '<controller><action>/' => '<controller>/<action>/'
            ),   
        ),</pre>

Comment: I think .htaccess needs to be viewed. Try to add this directives


`RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap tolowercase int:tolower 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${tolowercase:$1} [R=301,L]`